# Can we implement Web session management relying on HTTPS protocol

Tags: security, web

Webserver provide explicit session management as HTTP protocol is stateless.
Suppose if I am writing a new web server and I know that I will support only HTTPS can I rely on HTTPS for session management?

Comment: HTTP ans HTTPS does not manage your application. How you want rely in HTTPS?

Comment: The 's' in https does not stand for state: it is just as stateless as http.

Comment: What do you mean can you? AFAIK (and I might be wrong) you can do pretty much the same thing in HTTP and HTTPS, the problem is how hard its to read the communication and where you would need to tap in. The only difference is the encryption of communication between browser and server. Also technically there are sessions involved, although on different network layers. I think TCP and SSL are session based. Not an expert though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.

Requiring a stable SSL/TLS session identifier (SSL_SESSION_ID) as essential for functionality is likely to break the site for too many real users. SSL clients aren't mandated to keep it the same over an extended period of time, and some browsers may not. I believe IE<8 can drop the connection and negotiate a new session arbitrarily.

There are also operational concerns... for example it'll break if you host it behind a terminating reverse proxy, and you'd have to be careful with caching as there is no `Vary:`-on-SSL-session-ID possible.

It certainly has interesting potential for tracking and risk rating as part of a wider system, but from what I've seen of people who've tried it (which does not include me, so take this with a pinch of salt) it's probably not a reliable replacement for cookies today.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: You can not manage your application state relying on HTTPS protocol. 
Both HTTP and HTTPS are stateless.
You should manage your application state using your Web Server session management.